# Are there any historically significant volcanic eruptions that predate Akrotiri?

Tags: bronze-age, disasters

Specifically, any that occurred after the first civilizations developed, but before the Minoan eruption on Santorini (Thera/Akrotiri). (Approx. 3500 – 1600 B.C.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Avellino eruption may slightly predate the Minoan catastrophe. It caused diverse climatic disturbances in the following years and brought us several archaeological remnants from the beginning of the Bronze Age in Italy.